# Prevent jquery slider being clicked a hundred times = 100 animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building my first simple accordian type thing (without any net tuts), the js I have is this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('#one').css("height", "25");
    $('#dtwo').css("height", "25"); 
    $('#three').css("height", "25");   
        $('#one').click(function() {
          if ($('#one').hasClass("extended")) {
            $('#one').animate({height: '25px'},500);
            $('#one').removeClass("extended");
            $('#a1').animate({opacity: '1'},500);
          } else {
            $('#one').animate({height: '120px'},500);
            $('#one').addClass("extended");
            $('#a1').animate({opacity: '0'},300);
          }
    });
});
```

Which works fine.

However you can click it like 200 times and it will do it 200 times, how can I prevent this?

Comment: Do you mean you want to limit the number of times the accordian can be opened and closed? Or is there some problem with the animation? I'm having trouble understanding what you mean.

Comment: hi, im sorry. I mean like.. so someone doesnt spam click it so it opens closes opens closes opens closes all within a second; its less professional imho

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If youre talking about the animation queuing up, you could use the [stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) method. Something like this:

```
$('#a1').stop(true).animate({opacity: '1'},500);
```

Passing `true` as the first argument will clear the queue.

> **clearQueue** A Boolean indicating whether to remove queued animation as well. Defaults to false.

If you are experiencing trobule with the animation stopping half way due to the clearQueue bool you can try using `stop(true, true)` instead.

> **jumpToEnd** A Boolean indicating whether to complete the current animation immediately. Defaults to false.

Comment: Hi Johan, thanks for the answer! Will accept when it lets me :-) thanks for the explanation too!

Comment: `stop()` needs to be run on the element that youre animating (`$('#a1')` in this case.) It would be great if you could post a jsfiddle with your problem

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following (not tested, but you get the general idea):

```
if ($('#one').hasClass("extended")) {
        if ($('#one').data("inProgress")) return;
        $('#one').data("inProgress", true);
        $('#one').animate({height: '25px'},500);
        $('#one').removeClass("extended");
        $('#a1').animate({opacity: '1'},500);
        $('#one').data("inProgress", false);
      } else {
        if ($('#one').data("inProgress")) return;
        $('#one').data("inProgress", true);
        $('#one').animate({height: '120px'},500);
        $('#one').addClass("extended");
        $('#a1').animate({opacity: '0'},300);
        $('#one').data("inProgress", false);
      }
```